# Folder/subfolder size then deletion

Tags: linux, shell, directory, size, delete-file

I am new in the world of Linux:please, accept my apology for this question:

I have written a script which check the size of a folder and ALL of its subfolder and if the size is greater than X bytes then  files which have been modified more than X days ago will be deleted.

I have put folder size zero for test purpose, therefore,  the script should have perform the deletion process, but, it does NOT.

This script does do what I expect and I do not know why.

Thanks for your help.
Script is:

```
#!/bin/sh

# 100GB SIZE LIMIT
SIZE="0"

# check the current size
CHECK="`du /media/nssvolumes/TEST/MB/`"

if ["$CHECK" -gt "$SIZE"]; then echo "$ACTION"
ACTION="`find /media/nssvolumes/TEST/MB/ -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 3 -mtime +1 -type f  -exec rm -f {} \;`"
else exit
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here we have a bunch of errors.
Supposing your OS is Linux, try running `du` from the command line to realise what it returns, because it is NOT a number.

- Second problem - using of `[]` requires spaces.
- Also, integers does not require `""`
- You're printing  $ACTION before its value is defined.
- exit is not needed to be called if script has no more code to execute

So the fixed script is:

```
#!/bin/sh

# 100GB SIZE LIMIT
SIZE=0
MY_DIR="/media/nssvolumes/TEST/MB/"

# check the current size
CHECK=$(du -bs $MY_DIR|awk '{print $1}')

if [ $CHECK -gt $SIZE ]; then
    echo "ACTION"
    find $MY_DIR -mindepth 0 -maxdepth 3 -mtime +1 -type f -exec rm {} \;    
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the script: what happen if size is below the limit? no "else" and "exit" are required? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: In script as we have it now, there is no code after the if-block. So the script will terminate anyway. But if you are going to write more code, then you might want to add some 'else' or explicit 'exit.